# How to plot a zero-order function on a scatterplot?

Tags: r, plot

I would like to make a plot from a pairs of x-y values, but instead of the normal linear connection between the dots, I would like them to be connected only by horizontal and vertical lines (zero-order fit). Is this possible in R ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the option to make a step plot (I think this is what you're after?).  This is done with the `type="s"` option to `plot`.

```
set.seed(0)
dat <- data.frame(x=sample(10), y=sample(10))
plot(dat[order(dat$x),], type="s")
points(dat, pch=16, col="steelblue")
```

[image]